# When click on tab, add same data in ListView continue

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I am using Tab Layout. I am showing data in ListView inside ListFragment. Data is showing in ListView but problem is when we press tabb again, same data will add in Listview. So every time continue same data add in listView.

Code here-

```
public class HomeFragments extends ListFragment {

int[] ust_icon = {R.drawable.title,R.drawable.t2,R.drawable.t2};
String[] live_on = {"NA","NA","NA"};
String[] total_subtopics = {"3","3","3"};
String[] title = {"semiconductor devices ##","Equations of state ##","pn junction ##"};
String[] pos = {"1","5","6"};
String[] completed_subtopics = {"3","3","3"};
String[] live = {"false","false","false"};
String[] id = {"13","14","15"};


ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
SimpleAdapter adapter;

public HomeFragments() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_fragments, container, false);

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("ust_icon", Integer.toString(ust_icon[i]));
        map.put("live_on",live_on[i]);
        map.put("total_subtopics",total_subtopics[i]);
        map.put("title",title[i]);
        map.put("pos",pos[i]);
        map.put("completed_subtopics",completed_subtopics[i]);
        map.put("live",live[i]);
        map.put("id",id[i]);

        data.add(map);
    }



    String[] from = {"ust_icon","live_on","total_subtopics","title","pos","completed_subtopics","live","id"};

    int[] to = {R.id.img1,R.id.txt1,R.id.txt2,R.id.txt3,R.id.txt4,R.id.txt5,R.id.txt6,R.id.txt7};


    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),data, R.layout.list1, from, to);

    setListAdapter(adapter);


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}
```

}

how to resolve this issue Please help....

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: on scrolling tab, same data is adding multiple times. i just want, same data should not be multiple time in listview

Answer (score 0):

I think I have your answer. Just wait for me a couple minute when I got home and then I’ll answer you ok?

**Edit:**
Try to construct your data and set your adapter in onActivityCreated()

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_fragments, container, false);

    return view;
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("ust_icon", Integer.toString(ust_icon[i]));
        map.put("live_on",live_on[i]);
        map.put("total_subtopics",total_subtopics[i]);
        map.put("title",title[i]);
        map.put("pos",pos[i]);
        map.put("completed_subtopics",completed_subtopics[i]);
        map.put("live",live[i]);
        map.put("id",id[i]);

        data.add(map);
    }



    String[] from = {"ust_icon","live_on","total_subtopics","title","pos","completed_subtopics","live","id"};

    int[] to = {R.id.img1,R.id.txt1,R.id.txt2,R.id.txt3,R.id.txt4,R.id.txt5,R.id.txt6,R.id.txt7};


    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),data, R.layout.list1, from, to);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

if the code above not working, try to replace this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

by this: `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data;`

and then in your **onCreateView** : `data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`

Comment: This is not an answer. Please add it as a comment.

Comment: @Pawansingh ok I'm home, can you email me your project?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding condition to your code like i did below.i just created boolean variable called **check**.if tab opens first time it will set listview as well as set it's value to true.now condition wont run and you will not get listview element add again and again

```
public class HomeFragments extends ListFragment {

int[] ust_icon = {R.drawable.title,R.drawable.t2,R.drawable.t2};
String[] live_on = {"NA","NA","NA"};
String[] total_subtopics = {"3","3","3"};
String[] title = {"semiconductor devices ##","Equations of state ##","pnjunction ##"};
String[] pos = {"1","5","6"};
String[] completed_subtopics = {"3","3","3"};
String[] live = {"false","false","false"};
String[] id = {"13","14","15"};
public static final boolean check = false;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
SimpleAdapter adapter;

public HomeFragments() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_fragments, container, false);

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ust_icon", Integer.toString(ust_icon[i]));
    map.put("live_on",live_on[i]);
    map.put("total_subtopics",total_subtopics[i]);
    map.put("title",title[i]);
    map.put("pos",pos[i]);
    map.put("completed_subtopics",completed_subtopics[i]);
    map.put("live",live[i]);
    map.put("id",id[i]);

    data.add(map);
}

 if(check == false)
{
String[] from = {"ust_icon","live_on","total_subtopics","title","pos","completed_subtopics","live","id"};

int[] to = {R.id.img1,R.id.txt1,R.id.txt2,R.id.txt3,R.id.txt4,R.id.txt5,R.id.txt6,R.id.txt7};


adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),data, R.layout.list1, from, to);

setListAdapter(adapter);
check = true;
}

return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
super.onStart();

}
```